# Can't set boolean values when import data from csv to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, csv, import

I have built a task to import data like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|  
  question = Question.new ({  
  content:   row[0],
  mark:      row[1],
  topic_id:  row[2],
  question_type_id: row[3],
  answers_attributes: [
    { content: row[5], correct: row[6] },
    { content: row[7], correct: row[8] }
  ]
})
question.user_id = row[4]
question.save!
```

This is my CSV file:

```
content, mark, topic_id, question_type_id, user_id, content, correct, content, correct
_____ are people involved in or affected by project activities, 5, 16, 1, 3, True, 't', False, 'f'
```

But when i run import task, the `correct attribute` always is FALSE in database, i have tried with different [Boolean Data Type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-boolean.html) of PostgreSQL but not working. What do i wrong?

Comment: Please show us the (generated) SQL. I looks like the 't' and 'f' fields are superfluous/ redundant.

Comment: @DipakPanchal it has error: `Illegal quoting in line 2.`  
@wildplasser how can i show SQL when i use `rake import` ?

Comment: the results not change, two answer row still have value of correct column is `FALSE`

Comment: still the same result, both answer is `FALSE` (it is default value i set for `correct` column), i have tried all values in [Boolean Data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-boolean.html).

Comment: If you don't use postgres for importing the csv: please remove the postgres tag. The {content,correct} fields still look duplicate to me.

Comment: Hey, i import data from csv file to postgres database, so i tried with Boolean Data Type of PostgreSQL, if not, why i tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It is in the csv file:

```
content, mark, topic_id, question_type_id, user_id, content, correct, content, correct
_____ are people involved in or affected by project activities, 5, 16, 1, 3, True, 1, False, 0
```

The problem here is the space before the value of boolean column. In the csv file above, the space between `True, 1` is a problem. When the csv file is imported to the database, it includes the space in front of `1`, so the value imported was `" 1"`, not `"1"`, so postgresql cannot recognize the value with a space. I removed the space before it and it works now, this is my correct csv file (I removed all spaces):

```
content,mark,topic_id,question_type_id,user_id,content,correct,content,correct
_____ are people involved in or affected by project activities,5,16,1,3,True,1,False,0
```

Maybe this helps for SO if someone has a problem like me with spaces in CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing True/False with true/false

```
1.9.3-p194 :006 > True
NameError: uninitialized constant True
from (irb):6
from /Users/SAdvincula/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p194 :007 > true
=> true
```

Comment: i tried it, but not works :( ah, `True` and `False` in my csv, it is the content of answer, 't' and 'f' are values i use to set boolean value

Answer (score 0):

Change your csv file

```
content, mark, topic_id, question_type_id, user_id, content, correct, content, correct
_____ are people involved in or affected by project activities, 5, 16, 1, 3, True, '1', False, '0'
```

Comment: what is your 'f' and 't'? if it is boolean value and use 1 for true and 0 for false

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand, `True` and `False` are values of `content` column, change it just change the answers's content of question. 'f' and 't' are values to set [boolean data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-boolean.html)

Comment: anyway, thanks for helps, i will post answer when i found the problem :)